# Name of the object to be paired against

Tags: single-word-requests

If I have a single object (example: the Ace of Spades) and a list of objects (example: A full deck of cards) which I would then attempt to match against the singular object, like in the game of snap.

What would I call the list of objects I'd be matching against?

Suitors works, in the context of dating, but I am looking for a more general term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **[candidate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/candidate)**

> a person or thing regarded as suitable or likely for a particular fate or position

Answer (score 0):

counterpart, equivalent, peer, parallel, complement, match, twin, mate, fellow, brother, sister, analogue, partner, correlative; copy, duplicate, compeer, coequal

Answer (score 0):

A **set** is a collection of objects. [In mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29), they are distinct objects. [In common usage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set), a set is a collection of objects, usually having one or more common attributes: A chess set is  collection of objects that are to be used together; a set of books may be all on the same topic; a set of knives may be a collection of knives for different special purposes.

However, with cards, *set* may also refer to [a collection of cards of the same rank](http://www.pagat.com/invented/10_phases.html). But, in this case, the set you referred to in your example is more properly called a *deck* (which you already called it).

Another choice is **assortment**, which is a [mixed collection](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assortment). A standard deck of playing cards is an assortment (a mixed collection) of cards of four suits and thirteen values.

And, of course, the words *collection* and *group* are suitable here, as well as some of their many synonyms.