# Names for matching things

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

The context here is programming, so I'm not sure if anyone could understand.

I have a function that takes in two parameters. The first parameter is an `enum` while the second parameter is a list (of `enum`). What the function does is to search through the list to see if any of the `enum` matches the first `enum` parameter.

I'm trying to come up with appropriate names for the two parameters. Initially, I named the first parameter `matchWith` and the second parameter `matchAgainst`. Then I looked at it and felt that something is definitely wrong with these names.

I have read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151215/name-of-the-object-to-be-paired-against), which would make the second parameter into `candidates`, but would still left me clueless how to name the first parameter.

What are some suitable choices for my case?

Comment: They are *element* (or *item*) and *set* perhaps. You check if "element" is a member of "set".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "[Naming, including naming programming variables/classes](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Python uses "needle" and "haystack". You always look for a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you search for matching items from a list, and having looked [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) and [here](https://matrix.squiz.net/manuals/search/chapters/search-list), perhaps something like this:

`itemFound = findItem (searchItem, resourceList)`